# What does the --projects flag do in Maven?

Tags: maven-2

I have a Maven project which has many a set of customer-specific modules of which one is used.  The command to execute this build is as follows:

```
mvn clean install --projects [targetModule] --also-make
```

Normally I would use profiles to configure module selection and it appears that the end result is similar in this case.  I cannot seem to find any documentation on this --projects flag and its semantics which is making me hesitant to specific a different set of modules. Does anyone know how --projects and/or --also-make works or where I might find documentation on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mvn --help` gives some information regarding this.

```
 -am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects required by the
                                        list

 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Build specified reactor projects
                                        instead of all projects
```